# getting error while installing ubuntu 20.04 on virtual box in windows10

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, windows

I am getting an error while installing ubuntu-20.04.3 on virtual box on windows 10.
The error is like this. what should I do?

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine ubuntu-20.04.3.

```
Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include all steps needed to reproduce the error. Are you following some guide? Link to that too. Also share the research you found before asking.

Comment: This is an error with VirtualBox on Windows10, not with the guest OS. The question may be better answered [on the VirtualBox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org) 

Comment: The hint is "AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS" which means check the BIOS of your system.